old numega's boundschecker doesn't work on windows10?
I downloaded numega boundschecker trial version for vc 6.0.
When running it, it made first error exception with 0xc0000005 error code.
I found it could be occurred by anti virus vaccine, but I don't have it.
I had runned and checked it running ok about 20 years, but it was on win XP.
This time, I runned it on window 10, this makes numega's boundschecker doesn't work on windows 10?
Thanks.

According to Wikipedia, ...The current version (12.1.40) of BoundsChecker supports 32-bit and 64-bit native applications on Windows 10 (2020 Spring Update)...
